# Websocket client in Python - is there a way to receive a specific response from a past subscription?

Tags: python, websocket

I'm using the websocket library in Python3 (installed as websocket-client) as the client in an API. I connect to the server with the following command:

```
ws = websocket.WebSocket(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE});
ws.connect("wss://here_comes_the_url");
```

I have previously subscribed to several "events" using:

```
ws.send(json.dumps({"queryId":"A_UNIQUE_VALUE", "msg_type":"subscription", "subscriptionType":"SUBSCRIBE", ...}));
```

Now I want to get responses. If I connect and do:

```
result =  ws.recv();
```

I get a response for one of the subscriptions done previously. However, I have no idea to which subscription I will get a response. They seem to cycle, one by one, until it reaches the one I want.

Is there a way to receive a specific response from a specific subscription using, for instance, the unique queryId provided earlier?

Thanks!

Comment: Create multiple connections for different subscriptions? This will all depend on which service you are connecting to.

Comment: If I subscribe to a feed in one connection, close that connection, then connect again I still get a response from the feed previously subscribed to. If I subscribed to 1000 feeds, during every connection the `recv()` function will cycle through the 1000 feeds.